# Python - delete object that points to another object

Tags: python, list, filter

I have a list of tuples like below:

```
In [136]: z
Out[136]: 
[(0, array([ 0.71428571,  2.92857143,  1.64285714,  1.07142857])),
 (1, array([ 2.89473684,  1.68421053,  0.52631579,  3.21052632])),
 (2, array([ 1.03571429,  1.5       ,  2.75      ,  2.96428571])),
 (3, array([ 3.35714286,  2.07142857,  3.        ,  1.28571429])),
 (0, array([ 5.234324  ,  3.234324  ,  4.        ,  2.34534534])),
 (4, array([ 0.6,  0.1,  2.6,  0.4]))]
```

and a list of strings like below:

```
In [138]: b 
Out[138]: ['Sam', 'Rachel', 'Mosses', 'Roth', 'Wilhelm']
```

The integer in `z` points to a string in `b`.

For example, the vectors `(0, array([ 0.71428571,  2.92857143,  1.64285714,  1.07142857]))` and `(0, array([ 5.234324  ,  3.234324  ,  4.        ,  2.34534534]))` both  represent `'Sam'` (which is `b[0]`).

I want to delete an entry from `b`. In result, all vectors in `z` pointing to this removed entry will be deleted.

For example, if I will delete `'Sam'`, I want my new `z` to become:

```
In [136]: z
Out[136]: 
[(0, array([ 2.89473684,  1.68421053,  0.52631579,  3.21052632])),
 (1, array([ 1.03571429,  1.5       ,  2.75      ,  2.96428571])),
 (2, array([ 3.35714286,  2.07142857,  3.        ,  1.28571429])),
 (3, array([ 0.6,  0.1,  2.6,  0.4]))]

In [138]: b 
Out[138]: ['rachel', 'mosses', 'roth', 'wilhelm']
```

Comment: How would you remove 'Sam' from `b`? Would you look for 'Sam' in `b` or do you have the `index 0` to be removed from `b`?

Comment: Do you mean you just want to remove an element from a list?  Just `b.pop(0)`?

Comment: I look for 'Sam' in `b`, and then I know the `index`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't try but probably something like (where `k` is the key to be removed; in your example `k=0`):

```
z = [ (e[0] - (e[0]>k), e[1]) for e in z if e[0] != k ]
```

**Explanations:** you can have a filter effect in a list comprehension with the syntax `for e in z if`; you can also substract 1 to the initial key when greater than k by using the arithmetic value of `(e[0]>k)`.